# can't install mbstring php...missing libgmp.so.3

Tags: php, linux

I just install php 5.4.16 on RHEL but am looking to install mbstring too. When I try to install it via yum...I get a dependency error on libgmp.so.3

```
[root@ip-108-205-20-169 ec2-user]# yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.0.2-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-common(x86-64) = 7.0.2-1.w6 for package: php70w-mbstring-7.0.2-1.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w-common.x86_64 0:7.0.2-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: php70w-common-7.0.2-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.2-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php70w-common-7.0.2-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

EDIT:

tried to install the 5.4 mbstring but am still getting the same error related to libgmp.so.3

```
[root@ip-108-205-20-169 ec2-user]# yum install php54w-mbstring-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php54w-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.45-2.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-2.w6 for package: php54w-mbstring-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php54w-common.x86_64 0:5.4.45-2.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: php54w-common-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php54w-common-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

in my /usr/lib64 dir...I have a libgmp.so.10....but don't see a .3

Comment: your repo setup is incorrect, and is trying to stuff a v7 library into a v5.4.16 install.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install mbstring for php7, but your current php version installed is 5.4. You could remove `php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64` and instead install `php70w-common-7.0.2-1.w6.x86_64`, or you could locate mbstring for php5.4 if you don't want to upgrade to 7.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4.16 is the default version provided in CentOS 7

You don't need any additional repository (especially webtatic which raise such conflicts).

Mixing repository for 6 and 7 can"t work.

Fix your repository configuration, and then like for all extensions

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case you should update the release to 7:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.innosol.asia/remi/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum install php71
yum install php71-php-mysqlnd php71-php-pecl-imagick php71-php-mcrypt php71-php-mbstring  php71-php-pecl-zip php71-php-devel php71-php-gd php71-php-pear
```

then you should use yum to list the

```
yum list *mbstring*
```

and install it use yum.